# 'database name must be a string' Error when connecting with my Connection String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am attempting to connect to MongoDB via the package `mongoose`, but get an error along the lines of `MongoError: database name must be a string`.

I am using Windows, within the script I am also connecting to 2 other APIs which are both connected. I have tried adding my database name when requiring mongoose and also when connecting (`.MyDatabaseName` to the end).

```
Mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://MyUserName:MyPassword@williamdata7kmxm.mongodb.net", {useNewUrlParser: true}).EternalsMilitary;

Mongoose.connect.once("open", function() {  
    console.log("Connected To MongoDB");
}).on("error", function(err) {
    console.log("Error Connecting To MongoDB: ", err);
});
```

It's expected to output `connected`, but it errors with `MongoError: database name must be a string`.

Comment: try this: `mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://MyUserName:MyPassword@williamdata7kmxm.mongodb.net/', {dbName: 'yourDbName'});`   Adding the dbname since you're using the mongodb+srv syntax

Answer (score 13):

I needed to include the database name inside of the URI string. For example... `mongodb+srv://MyUserName:MyPassword@williamdata7kmxm.mongodb.net/MyDatabaseName`
This will then point it to that specific database.

Answer (score 6):

For whatever reason the new url parser doesn't seem to work with certain URLs.

As a quick fix you can try reverting back to the old one with `{ useNewUrlParser: false }`

Comment: I already have a fix, using the new URL parser. Thanks anyway though

Comment: @William please do share your fix, if you have time :-)

Comment: I apologize, should I put it in this comment section?

Comment: @William it's possible to answer your own question, that would be a great :)

Comment: connection works, but  throws deprecation warning saying it should be true

Comment: It just works. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your URI after where it says mongodb.net put slash and the name of the database for example:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@<instance>.mongodb.net/**nameDatabase**', {dbName: "Eclipse"}, {useNewUrlParser: true})
```

Comment: Aside from replying to a question over 2 years old, please don't propagate credentials (those are "live" creds - I tested). I edited them out of your answer (though anyone with enough rep can see them)

Comment: I just copied them from the comments above as an example and wanted to explain it in a different way for other people to see this, I didn't think anyone would be offended

Comment: Also I'm new and I can see them so anyone can see them

Comment: This has nothing to do with being offended. The OP made a mistake, publishing real credentials in a comment (if it was in their original question, I could have easily edited them out). This is something to be aware of in the future, to ensure you never re-broadcast such a thing. As I already said, I took care of it. And as far as who can see your answer's history: only people with several thousand rep points can see the edit history and non-edited username/password (not talking about you, as you are the author of your answer).